# Backbone add member to model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

**How to add "member" to Backbone model properly?**
(I use RubyOnRails as a backend.) 
`routes.rb`

```
resources :products, only: :show do
  member do
    get :add_product # "/products/126/add_product.json"
  end
end
```

`app/assets/javascript/views/products/show.js.coffee`

```
class Shop.Views.ProductsShow extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'click #add-to-cart': 'addToCart'

  addProduct: ->
    $.ajax
      dataType: 'json'
      url: @model.url() + '/add_product.json'
      type: 'GET'
      success: ->
        console.log 'ADDED!'
```

Response is 200 OK (backend does the action correctly), but i **can not get** `ADDED!` message in my js console.

What i did wrong?

And second question: **where should i store my products member** `add_product`, in model or in view or elsewhere?
Thanks.

Comment: (1) Using a GET request to modify something is strange. (2) Why not have a Backbone collection to represent the cart and then saying [`cart.create(...)`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) to add something to it? (3) Have you checked what your controller is sending back in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: I thought about it, that `add_product` action should be a part of cart entity with `create` action (when I had not found solution for member action in Backbone documentation). It seems as Backbone rescues from bad design solutions :). Could I ask you one more question: "I don't want create `cart` entity, just use for the purpose `orders` which handles states ("started", "finished" and etc.) with state_machine. Is it good design solution? Is there weaknesses?

Comment: I don't know `state_machine` but having a separate `Cart` in both the server and client makes sense to me. You need somewhere to put a list of things in the order and that's usually called a shopping cart so there you go.

Comment: I'll think about it. You could issue first comment as answer to the topic. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a design change.

Using a GET request to create or modify something is a bit strange, especially in a RESTful environment like Backbone talking to Rails.

Instead, I'd recommend a collection in Backbone (a "cart") and in Rails (a `Cart` which `has_many :items`). Then you can say `cart.create(product_attributes)` in your Backbone code and all the usual RESTful stuff in Backbone and Rails should do The Right Thing all by itself.